# Run SQL script on multiple DB connections at same time in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 4 different database connections in Oracle SQL Developer. All of them have the exact same set of packages and procedures. Every time I change something in my scripts I have to run it on all of the connections one-by-one. Is there no way to run it on all the connections at the same time?

Comment: Why run the same script on 4 different connections?

Comment: Because I want all of them to have the procedures I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can only execute SQL developer queries on different connections using the GUI.

You should, however, be able to acheive what you want using SQLPlus instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "create database link" function:

```
          CREATE DATABASE LINK linkDB_1
            CONNECT TO xxxx IDENTIFIED BY xxxx
            USING 'xxxxx';


            SELECT *
            FROM   tablename@linkDB_1;

            DROP DATABASE LINK linkdb_1;
```

I tested on my SQL Navigator, and it works.